# How to add a get value php into bootstrap toggle collapse?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

i've an id number that i want to throw with methode get php into bootstrap toggle button, and how can class="collapse" get the id number form the button and show it with include php? 
the simple code like this :

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rencanaterus">Lihat Pengeluaran</button>
<!--how to add get value php inside from the button?-->

        <div id="rencanaterus" class="collapse">
        <? 
        $_GET['idspd'] = 13;
        include 'my_table.php';?>
          </div>
```

i want it will be show the link like this www.mywebsite.com/my_table.php?idspd=13

before, thanks for your attention.

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked exactly, but you can "embed" php variables into HTML code in PHP, i.e. `<a href="www.mywebsite.com/my_table.php?idspd=<?php echo $id; ?>">` or using short syntax, if it's not disabled in php.ini: `<a href="www.mywebsite.com/my_table.php?idspd=<?=$id?>">`

Comment: usually it will be like this in a button : <a href="mytable.php?id=<?$id?>" type="button"/>
the exact question is how can it apply in bootstrap button data toggle collapse?